# RSA Decryption using OpenSSL

Tags: rsa

Trying to decrypt RSA Ciphertext with a private key using OpenSSl

Used rsatool to generate a .pem file for private key which is 1022 bit long.

Converted the original cyphertext 1023 bits long from just numbers to hex values of bytes

I have used the command: openssl pkeyutl -decrypt -in C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Cypher.txt -out C:\Users\abc\Desktop\result.txt -inkey C:\Users\abc\Desktop\key.pem

But received an error of: Public Key operation error
804C0000:error:0200006C:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:data greater than mod len:crypto\rsa\rsa_ossl.c:406:

How can we solve this problem to get the plaintext?

Answer (score 1):

> Used rsatool to generate a .pem file for private key which is 1022 bit long.
>
> Converted the original cyphertext 1023 bits long from just numbers to hex values of bytes

The result of an RSA operation is always a value smaller than the modulus size; that size is conventionally denoted as the key size.

If you do have an RSA key whose modulus is $< 2^{1022}$ (which is implied by the statement that the "private key  [is] 1022 bit long), then it cannot generate a ciphertext $> 2^{1022}$ (which is implied by the statement that "the original cyphertext [is] 1023 bits long".

Because of this, OpenSSL is rejecting it, because this is impossible that this ciphertext correspond to this private key.

I suspect that you got either the private key or the ciphertext wrong (or the ciphertext doesn't, in fact, correspond to this key).  I personally suspect that you might have gotten the key wrong - "1022 bits" is an unusual size"; 1024 bits is more common (if generally viewed as insecure nowadays).